# jfreechart crashes when using Yahoo Finance Quotes

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, yahoo-finance

---

### QUESTION RESOLVED: solution is changing to JFreeChart v1.0.15

---

I have a very peculiar problem.

What I have set up is a file that sends a url request to the Yahoo Finance website and then uses the results to draw a JFreeChart in a JFrame.

What I just can't get my head around is the following:

**For certain url requests, the JFrame crashes**

It starts, but only shows a white screen. Whereas for other requests, my program works fine.

### Example

For example:

This request:

```
"http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2011&d=6&e=24&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv";
```

works fine.

But this request:

```
"http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=2&b=1&c=2012&d=6&e=24&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv";
```

causes an error.

How is this possible?

### Note

I know the following:

- JFrame crashes but JVM doesn't make note of it (doesn't notice that it crashes)
- Downloading of the stock quotes (the information that JFreeChart uses) goes perfect in both cases
- The code for downloading the data and displaying it in the JFreeChart comes from [this site](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=24521) (the code posted by *RoyW » Sat May 10, 2008 7:52 am*).
- The amount of data coming in doesn't seem a problem because in request 1, there are more data points than in request 2
- The way I download the data doesn't matter (I tried both reading directly from the url and I tried saving the `.csv` file to a folder and then reading from the folder)
- The problem doesn't occur randomly: I've tried launching the JFrame (recompiling the code and then running it) multiple times but the 'wrong' quote crashes the JFrame everytime.

### Extra information

Something that might have to do with it:

- When I launch the graph with a correct quote and I drag the graph around, something weird happens. At a certain interval, it seems every weekend, the candlesticks get smaller and smaller untill they are only a stripe. Then when I drag across the weekend, they become thicker again until they are normal size again. This seems to happen for every weekend. Refer to the following pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So it got me thinking that it might have something to do with [trading days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trading_day). But this doesn't make any sense either because **1/1/2011** (request 1) falls on a Saturday and **3/1/2012** (request 2) falls on a Thursday while request 1 was successful and request 2 failed.

I am absolutely clueless as to what I should do.

All help greatly appreciated.

### Update

On request, here is the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with [trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod)'s suggestions (using JFreechart lib v1.0.14).

```
    import org.jfree.chart.*;
    import org.jfree.chart.axis.*;
    import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
    import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer;
    import org.jfree.data.xy.*;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.List;

    public class CandlestickDemo2 extends JFrame {
        public CandlestickDemo2(String stockSymbol) {
            super("CandlestickDemo");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            DateAxis    domainAxis       = new DateAxis("Date");
            NumberAxis  rangeAxis        = new NumberAxis("Price");
            CandlestickRenderer renderer = new CandlestickRenderer();
            XYDataset   dataset          = getDataSet(stockSymbol);

            XYPlot mainPlot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer);

            //Do some setting up, see the API Doc
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
            renderer.setDrawVolume(false);
            rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
            domainAxis.setTimeline( SegmentedTimeline.newMondayThroughFridayTimeline() );

            //Now create the chart and chart panel
            JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(stockSymbol, null, mainPlot, false);
            ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
            chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

            this.add(chartPanel);
            this.pack();
        }
        protected AbstractXYDataset getDataSet(String stockSymbol) {
            //This is the dataset we are going to create
            DefaultOHLCDataset result = null;
            //This is the data needed for the dataset
            OHLCDataItem[] data;

            //This is where we go get the data, replace with your own data source
            data = getData(stockSymbol);

            //Create a dataset, an Open, High, Low, Close dataset
            result = new DefaultOHLCDataset(stockSymbol, data);

            return result;
        }
        //This method uses yahoo finance to get the OHLC data
        protected OHLCDataItem[] getData(String stockSymbol) {
            List<OHLCDataItem> dataItems = new ArrayList<OHLCDataItem>();
            try {
                String strUrl= "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=2&b=1&c=2012&d=6&e=24&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv";
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");

                String inputLine;
                in.readLine();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, ",");

                    Date date       = df.parse( st.nextToken() );
                    double open     = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double high     = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double low      = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double close    = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double volume   = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double adjClose = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );

                    OHLCDataItem item = new OHLCDataItem(date, open, high, low, close, volume);
                    dataItems.add(item);
                }
                in.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Data from Yahoo is from newest to oldest. Reverse so it is oldest to newest
            Collections.reverse(dataItems);

            //Convert the list into an array
            OHLCDataItem[] data = dataItems.toArray(new OHLCDataItem[dataItems.size()]);

            return data;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new CandlestickDemo2("GOOG").setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This generates a JFrame that displays nothing but a white screen. Try changing the `strUrl` to

```
 "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2011&d=6&e=24&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv";
```

and you will notice that it works fine.

### Update

**Solved it!** The problem was the JFreeChart version. Changing from v1.0.14 to v1.0.15 solved everything. Kudos to [trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod) for (unknowingly) solving my issue by answering extensively *and mentioning the library version* used.

Does anybody know how I can help others that are having the same issue? Is there a portal somewhere where I can make note of this bug?

Comment: *"**Extra information**"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Please read my third point in the **Note** section. Thank you

Comment: @nachokk: It crashes by not displaying **anything**. Whereas normally, the JFrame shows several JButtons, JPanels etc..: now it just shows a white screen. So it launches, but displays nothing but a white 'container' so to speak. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: but the gui is freezing or something? May be you are blocking the `EDT` , are you using `SwingWorker` ?

Comment: @Jean-Paul  Please read my comment again.  It does not recommend 'linking to code' but 'posting an SSCCE'.  I do not know whether that link leads to an SSCCE but if it is, *edit it into the question.*  Links outside SO tend to rot, and many people will not be willing, or able, to follow external links.

Comment: @AndrewThompson makes a compelling case, but the [author](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2592874/david-gilbert) has maintained the forum for over a decade.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I've added the SSCCE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`CandlestickDemo`](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=24521) works for me with [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) v1.0.15 and either of your queries. I made two changes:

- Construct the GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); failure to do so causes a data race with non-deterministic results:

  ```
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          new CandlestickDemo("GOOG").setVisible(true);
      }
  });
  ```
- Omit the backing buffer, although it's probably irrelevant:

  ```
  ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
  ```
- Addendum: For reference, it looks like a call to `ParamChecks.nullNotPermitted()` was [applied](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2900/tree/branches/jfreechart-1.0.x-branch/source/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/CandlestickRenderer.java) in [r2692](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2692/), replacing an explicit check, but the renderer was otherwise unchanged.
- Addendum: Under v1.0.14, the example works correctly with the `DefaultTimeline` of [`DateAxis`](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2900/tree/branches/jfreechart-1.0.x-branch/source/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.java), which [changed substantially](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2900/log/?path=/branches/jfreechart-1.0.x-branch/source/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.java) in the interim.
- Addendum: @David Gilbert notes that the relevant changes may be found in [r2465](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2465/).

[image]

Comment: Your suggestions don't work; please see my update. I'm now going to change [tag:jfreechart] v1.0.14 to v1.0.15 to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: The library version did indeed solve the issue. Thank you so much for your precision, detailism and quick response! Awesome!

Comment: @Jean-Paul: Glad you got it sorted; sadly, I don't see a change that would account for your observation; more above.

Comment: Weird. I double checked [ceteris paribus](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/ceterisparibus.asp) and I'm 100% sure that it has to do with the change of library from v1.0.14 to v1.0.15. So somehow it must have effect.

Comment: I have to agree. Thank you for linking on [forum](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=24521#p176756).

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel like it, you can try my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419795/jfreechart-candlestick-chart-weird-behaviour-on-drag).

Comment: I just wanted to add that the update from 1.0.14 to 1.0.15 includes this bug fix which would explain the behavior: http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2465/

Comment: @DavidGilbert: Thanks! Answer updated. Please consider posting an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18419795/230513).