# JFreechart candlestick chart weird behaviour on drag

Tags: java, jfreechart, drag, candlestick-chart

This is a follow up question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413534/jfreechart-crashes-when-using-yahoo-finance-quotes).

What happens is the following:

When I launch the graph and I drag the graph around, something weird happens: at a certain interval, it seems every 7 periods, the candlesticks get smaller and smaller untill they are only a stripe. Then when I drag further, they become thicker again until they are normal size again. This seems to happen for every 7 periods.

An example of this phenomenon is displayed on to the following 3 pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The following code will show exactly what I mean. Just compile and run it.
Then press and hold `CTRL` and click and hold with your mouse on the graph. Now try dragging the graph to the right or left. After a certain 'dragging distance' you will notice the bug.

My question: How to prevent/ workaround this?

Code:

```
    import org.jfree.chart.*;
    import org.jfree.chart.axis.*;
    import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
    import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer;
    import org.jfree.data.xy.*;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.List;

    public class CandlestickDemo2 extends JFrame {
        public CandlestickDemo2(String stockSymbol) {
            super("CandlestickDemo");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            DateAxis    domainAxis       = new DateAxis("Date");
            NumberAxis  rangeAxis        = new NumberAxis("Price");
            CandlestickRenderer renderer = new CandlestickRenderer();
            XYDataset   dataset          = getDataSet(stockSymbol);

            XYPlot mainPlot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer);

            //Do some setting up, see the API Doc
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
            renderer.setDrawVolume(false);
            rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
            domainAxis.setTimeline( SegmentedTimeline.newMondayThroughFridayTimeline() );

            //Now create the chart and chart panel
            JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(stockSymbol, null, mainPlot, false);
            ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
            chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

            mainPlot.setDomainPannable(true);
            mainPlot.setRangePannable(true);

            this.add(chartPanel);
            this.pack();
        }
        protected AbstractXYDataset getDataSet(String stockSymbol) {
            //This is the dataset we are going to create
            DefaultOHLCDataset result = null;
            //This is the data needed for the dataset
            OHLCDataItem[] data;

            //This is where we go get the data, replace with your own data source
            data = getData(stockSymbol);

            //Create a dataset, an Open, High, Low, Close dataset
            result = new DefaultOHLCDataset(stockSymbol, data);

            return result;
        }
        //This method uses yahoo finance to get the OHLC data
        protected OHLCDataItem[] getData(String stockSymbol) {
            List<OHLCDataItem> dataItems = new ArrayList<OHLCDataItem>();
            try {
                String strUrl= "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=2&b=1&c=2013&d=4&e=24&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv";
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");

                String inputLine;
                in.readLine();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, ",");

                    Date date       = df.parse( st.nextToken() );
                    double open     = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double high     = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double low      = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double close    = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double volume   = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                    double adjClose = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );

                    OHLCDataItem item = new OHLCDataItem(date, open, high, low, close, volume);
                    dataItems.add(item);
                }
                in.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Data from Yahoo is from newest to oldest. Reverse so it is oldest to newest
            Collections.reverse(dataItems);

            //Convert the list into an array
            OHLCDataItem[] data = dataItems.toArray(new OHLCDataItem[dataItems.size()]);

            return data;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new CandlestickDemo2("GOOG").setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

### Update

This bug is now a reported bug issue on the sourceforge page of JFreeChart.

This bug can be tracked [**here**](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/bugs/1125/).

Comment: @assylias: So the only downside is an unevenly distributed axis? Can you show me how you modified the class?

Comment: I thought I had somewhat solved it but when I tried with your example I get a similar behaviour... Forget what I said. Sorry.

Comment: @assylias: Doesn't matter. It's just a very annoying problem with no easy fix I suppose.

Comment: I have spent quite some time on it a while ago and it was a headache - everytime I fixed something, it broke something else. My last thought (which I never tried) was to use a Text Axis instead of a DateAxis and manually populate the scale legend.

Comment: @assylias: It could work. Unfortunately, my program uses `dataset.getXValue(0, k)` and because I am using TimeSeries it is very important that the `XValue` is accurate (in milliseconds). Hence populating the scale legend with Strings (aka `String`s imitating `Date`s) would cause a major problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to reproduce the effect described. As [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18413534/230513), the effect is seen only with a `SegmentedTimeline`; it is not apparent with the `DefaultTimeline`. It appears to co-incide with dragging across the "hidden" weekends of a *monday-through-friday-timeline*, but I don't see an obvious bug.

One workaround might be to let the user choose the `TimeLine` using an adjacent control, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513). Because `DefaultTimeline` is `private`, you'll need to save the result from `getTimeline()` before calling `setTimeline()` in the control's handler.

Addendum: Here's a variation of the program that uses a `JCheckBox` to toggle the `Timeline`. Click the check box to enable the `SegmentedTimeline`; pan horizontally to see the effect (control-click on Windows; option-click on Mac).

[image: Default timeline]

[image: Segmented timeline]

```
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421887/230513
 * @see http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=24521
 */
public class CandlestickDemo2 extends JFrame {

    public CandlestickDemo2(String stockSymbol) {
        super("CandlestickDemo2");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("Date");
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Price");
        CandlestickRenderer renderer = new CandlestickRenderer();
        XYDataset dataset = getDataSet(stockSymbol);
        XYPlot mainPlot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer);
        //Do some setting up, see the API Doc
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setDrawVolume(false);
        rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        //Now create the chart and chart panel
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(stockSymbol, null, mainPlot, false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        mainPlot.setDomainPannable(true);
        mainPlot.setRangePannable(true);
        this.add(chartPanel);
        // Add tiemline toggle
        final Timeline oldTimeline = domainAxis.getTimeline();
        final Timeline newTimeline = SegmentedTimeline.newMondayThroughFridayTimeline();
        this.add(new JCheckBox(new AbstractAction("Segmented Timeline") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JCheckBox jcb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
                if (jcb.isSelected()) {
                    domainAxis.setTimeline(newTimeline);
                } else {
                    domainAxis.setTimeline(oldTimeline);
                }
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private AbstractXYDataset getDataSet(String stockSymbol) {
        //This is the dataset we are going to create
        DefaultOHLCDataset result;
        //This is the data needed for the dataset
        OHLCDataItem[] data;
        //This is where we go get the data, replace with your own data source
        data = getData(stockSymbol);
        //Create a dataset, an Open, High, Low, Close dataset
        result = new DefaultOHLCDataset(stockSymbol, data);
        return result;
    }
    //This method uses yahoo finance to get the OHLC data

    protected OHLCDataItem[] getData(String stockSymbol) {
        List<OHLCDataItem> dataItems = new ArrayList<OHLCDataItem>();
        try {
            String strUrl = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + stockSymbol
                + "&a=4&b=1&c=2013&d=6&e=1&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv";
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");
            String inputLine;
            in.readLine();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, ",");
                Date date = df.parse(st.nextToken());
                double open = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double high = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double low = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double close = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double volume = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double adjClose = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                OHLCDataItem item = new OHLCDataItem(date, open, high, low, close, volume);
                dataItems.add(item);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        //Data from Yahoo is from newest to oldest. Reverse so it is oldest to newest
        Collections.reverse(dataItems);
        //Convert the list into an array
        OHLCDataItem[] data = dataItems.toArray(new OHLCDataItem[dataItems.size()]);
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CandlestickDemo2("AAPL").setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But because I don't have data for the weekends, won't changing to `DefaultTimeline` change the units on the `x axis` such that gaps appear? Maybe for additional info: I have just found a similar question on [jfree](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=27794).

Comment: Yes; absent a fix, it's a trade-off. I'm not a fan of `SegmentedTimeline`, but a preference might be nice anyway. I notice `newFifteenMinuteTimeline()` pans OK.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Do you think a fix exists or is it impossible by construction? (If possible I will wait 2 days to start a bounty)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug or just an anomaly of the parent's implementation of `pan()`. Feel free to leave the question open. As you have an illustrated [sscce](http://sscce.org/), you might post in the forum or the project's bug tracker.  Use the `share` link above to get [announcer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) badge credit.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your time and the recommendations. I will try to get more attention drawn to it.

Comment: @trashgod Have you tried to use a "Text" axis instead of a DateAxis, and manually create the series? That should work but I've never tried to be honest.

Comment: @assylias: I see the same problem with synthetic data. I don't understand "Text" axis.

Comment: Showing the dates as strings and indexing the "active" days from 0 to n (instead of using milliseconds).