# ItemLabelPosition for multiple XYSeries on a XYLineChart - JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I'm trying to figure out how to control the labeling of 2 different XYSeries for a XYLineChart.  For example, I have a line series show the real market value of a home and another line series showing the maximum assessed value.  However, some of the labels on the lines overlap.  I was able to control the overall labeling of the lines by accessing the XYItemRenderer and ItemLabelPosition but this works as a whole.  I need to adjust the labeling on each individual line.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the visibility of the labels for each series using the renderer's method, [`setSeriesItemLabelsVisible()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setSeriesItemLabelsVisible-int-java.lang.Boolean-). Use a `JCheckBox`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421887/230513), or a `JComboBox`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), to allow the user to adjust the visibility as desired. Persist the user's choice using [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a bunch for your assistance.  You pointed me in the right direction.  Here is the process I used to control the item label position.

1. Get AbstractXYItemRenderer
2. Get ItemLabelPosition and customize
3. Set postion using setSeriesPositionItemLabelPosition method of AbstractXYItemRenderer

final AbstractXYItemRenderer xyRenderer = (AbstractXYItemRenderer) this.chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();

final ItemLabelPosition p1 = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.TOP_CENTER, TextAnchor.TOP_CENTER, - Math.PI / 4);
    xyRenderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(6.5);
    xyRenderer.setSeriesItemLabelPaint(1, Color.BLUE);
    xyRenderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(1, p1);

final ItemLabelPosition p2 = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE6, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER, - Math.PI / 4);
    xyRenderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(-8.5);
    xyRenderer.setSeriesItemLabelPaint(0, Color.RED);
    xyRenderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0, p2);