# JFreeChart Candlestick pointer

Tags: java, jfreechart, candlestick-chart

I have JFreeChart like this:

[image]

And I want to add mouse pointer to the chart similar to the HighCharts uses:

[image]

Here is my variation of the [code shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421887/230513) that creates the JFreeChart:

```
import org.jfree.data.xy.AbstractXYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultOHLCDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.*;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;


public class ChartOHLC extends ChartPanel {

    public ChartOHLC() {
        super(dajGraf());
        setMaximumDrawHeight(2000);
        setMaximumDrawWidth(3000);
    }

    public static JFreeChart dajGraf() {

        // premenne
        String stockSymbol = "AAPL";
        final DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("Date");
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Price");
        CandlestickRenderer renderer = new CandlestickRenderer();
        XYDataset dataset = getDataSet(stockSymbol);
        XYPlot mainPlot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer);

        //Do some setting up, see the API Doc
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setDrawVolume(false);
        rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

        //Now create the chart and chart panel
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(null, null, mainPlot, false);
        mainPlot.setDomainPannable(true);
        mainPlot.setRangePannable(true);
        return chart;
    }

   private static AbstractXYDataset getDataSet(String stockSymbol) {
        //This is the dataset we are going to create
        DefaultOHLCDataset result;
        //This is the data needed for the dataset
        OHLCDataItem[] data;
        //This is where we go get the data, replace with your own data source
        data = getData(stockSymbol);
        //Create a dataset, an Open, High, Low, Close dataset
        result = new DefaultOHLCDataset(stockSymbol, data);
        return result;
    }

   private static OHLCDataItem[] getData(String stockSymbol) {
        ArrayList<OHLCDataItem> dataItems = new ArrayList<OHLCDataItem>();
        try {
            String strUrl = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + stockSymbol + "&a=2&b=1&c=2014&d=3&e=1&f=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv";
            System.out.println(strUrl);
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");
            String inputLine;
            in.readLine();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, ",");
                Date date = df.parse(st.nextToken());
                double open = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double high = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double low = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double close = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double volume = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                double adjClose = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                OHLCDataItem item = new OHLCDataItem(date, open, high, low, close, volume);
                dataItems.add(item);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

        //Data from Yahoo is from newest to oldest. Reverse so it is oldest to newest
        Collections.reverse(dataItems);

        //Convert the list into an array
        OHLCDataItem[] data = dataItems.toArray(new OHLCDataItem[dataItems.size()]);
        return data;
    }

}
```

**Is is possible to add the mouse pointer to CandleStick JFreeChart?**

Comment: I usually use a tooltip.