# JFreechart program running, but window not displayed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfreechart

I am running code based on the example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18419795/230513) using Eclipse on OS X, and I am using the JFreeChart and JCommon libraries.

As i said in the title, the program is running but not displaying anything.
As check I have tried to print the data using the method printData() and it's working perfectly.
It correctly takes the data from a yahoo csv file.

I have even tried using a small bunch of data (20 rows), but it keeps not showing.

The problem may be just in displaying the JFrame window.

The code I have inserted trying to fix it is between //BEGIN and //END comments.

Waiting for a reply,

Thank you.

**SEMI-SOLVED:**
The code is fine, the problem is related to the JFreeChart Library.

I tried to "Build Path> Add my JFreeChart lib" in another previously working JFrame class.

When i insert the JFreeChart library, it inhibits the window display. Even if i don't import anything; just by adding the library to the building path.

As default system library i'm using "JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]".

**Code:**

```
package marketAnalyzer;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.MovingAverage;
import org.jfree.data.xy.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;



public class CandlestickDemo extends JFrame {


    public CandlestickDemo(String stockSymbol) {
        super("CandlestickDemo");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DateAxis    domainAxis       = new DateAxis("Date");
        NumberAxis  rangeAxis        = new NumberAxis("Price");
        CandlestickRenderer renderer = new CandlestickRenderer();
        XYDataset   dataset          = getDataSet(stockSymbol);

        XYPlot mainPlot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer);

        final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer maRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
        XYDataset              maSataset  = MovingAverage.createMovingAverage(dataset, "MA", 30 * ONE_DAY, 0);
        mainPlot.setRenderer(1, maRenderer);
        mainPlot.setDataset (1, maSataset);

        //Do some setting up, see the API Doc
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setDrawVolume(false);
        rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        domainAxis.setTimeline( SegmentedTimeline.newMondayThroughFridayTimeline() );

        //Now create the chart and chart panel
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(stockSymbol, null, mainPlot, false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

        this.add(chartPanel);
        this.pack();

        //BEGIN

        //TRYING TO DISPLAY THE WINDOW

        chartPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        chartPanel.validate();
        this.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        this.validate();
        chartPanel.repaint();
        this.repaint();


        //END
    }
    protected AbstractXYDataset getDataSet(String stockSymbol) {
        //This is the dataset we are going to create
        DefaultOHLCDataset result = null;
        //This is the data needed for the dataset
        OHLCDataItem[] data;

        //This is where we go get the data, replace with your own data source
        data = getData(stockSymbol);

        //Create a dataset, an Open, High, Low, Close dataset
        result = new DefaultOHLCDataset(stockSymbol, data);

        return result;
    }
    //This method uses yahoo finance to get the OHLC data
    protected OHLCDataItem[] getData(String stockSymbol) {
        List<OHLCDataItem> dataItems = new ArrayList<OHLCDataItem>();
        try {
            //INTERNET DATA
            //              String strUrl= "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+stockSymbol+"&a=0&b=1&c=2008&d=3&e=30&f=2008&ignore=.csv";
            //              URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            //              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            //              DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");


            //BEGIN
            FileReader r;
            BufferedReader in;

            r = new FileReader("nasdaqSmall.csv");

            in = new BufferedReader(r);
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");

            //END


            String inputLine;
            in.readLine();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, ",");

                Date date       = df.parse( st.nextToken() );
                double open     = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                double high     = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                double low      = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                double close    = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                double volume   = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
                double adjClose = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );

                OHLCDataItem item = new OHLCDataItem(date, open, high, low, close, volume);
                dataItems.add(item);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Data from Yahoo is from newest to oldest. Reverse so it is oldest to newest
        Collections.reverse(dataItems);

        //Convert the list into an array
        OHLCDataItem[] data = dataItems.toArray(new OHLCDataItem[dataItems.size()]);



        //BEGIN
        //DEBUG
        printData(data);
        //END

        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CandlestickDemo("MSFT").setVisible(true);

    }

    //PRINT DATA
    public static void printData(OHLCDataItem[] data){
        for(OHLCDataItem el: data){
            System.out.println(""+el.getDate()+" "+el.getOpen()+" "+el.getHigh()+" "+el.getLow()+" "+el.getClose()+
                    " "+el.getVolume());

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You are [required](http://stackexchange.com/legal) to cite the [original source code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18419795/230513), which works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this issue as well. It comes from adding all of the jars in the JFreeChart lib to the build path. By removing the unnecessary and adding only the **jfreechart-1.0.19** and **jcommon-1.0.23** jars, my applications started running with the window and chart displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how all the validate/repaints are going to help. As a general rule if you are going to change a container's layout manager, do it first and then add components to it.

JFrame's contain a JRootPane and this has a **contentPane**. Technically it's this contentPane which you need to add components too. You get to this using the frame's `getContentPane()` method. But that did become cumbersome so JFrame was made a little easier to use. From the docs:

> As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been
>   overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary. This means you
>   can write:
>
> ```
>    frame.add(child);
> ```
>
> And the child will be added to the contentPane.

But I can't remember when that convenience was added - possibly Java6 so be sure you're using at least jdk1.6.

The other thing to note is the contentPane's default layout:

> The default content pane will have a **BorderLayout** manager set on it.

So no need to set your frame to use the BorderLayout either. When using BorderLayout you ought to provide the location when adding a component, e.g. `BorderLayout.CENTER`. As it happens I don't think that's the cause of your bug as I think by default it assumes CENTER. But still, it's good practise.

I must admit that I always use the more verbose version and interact directly via `getContentPane()` for `add()` and `setLayout()` on JFrames rather than the convenience methods mainly from habit but it does make it clear what I am actually doing. I'd recommend you do the same for now.

I've created a smaller, simpler version of an app displaying a chart for you to work from.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.data.time.Day;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;

class Test {

    private JFrame frame;

    public Test() {

        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel aPanel = new JPanel();
        aPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));


        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(createChart());
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

        frame.getContentPane().add(chartPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart() {

        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("time series", Day.class);
        series.add(new Day(1,1,2014), 100 );  
        series.add(new Day(1,2,2014), 150);  
        series.add(new Day(1,3,2014), 70 );  
        series.add(new Day(1,4,2014), 210 );  
        series.add(new Day(1,5,2014), 310);
        series.add(new Day(1,6,2014), 260 );  
        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();  
        dataset.addSeries(series);  
        JFreeChart timechart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(  
                "Vistors Count Chart", // Title  
                "Date",         // X-axis Label 
                "Visitors",       // Y-axis Label  
                dataset,        // Dataset  
                true,          // Show legend  
                true,          // Use tooltips  
                false          // Generate URLs  
        );

        return timechart;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

This works using java/javac 1.7; jcommon-1.0.23; jfreechart-1.0.19.

Comment: "aPanel" does not appear to be used. It is never added to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your  class should `extends` the `ApplicationFrame` from the `import org.jfree.ui.` package.
 Now instead of using `frame.getContentPane()` use `setContentPane(myChartPanel)`.

Your code Should then look like:

```
final JFreeChart myChart = createChart(dataset);
    final ChartPanel myChartPanel = new ChartPanel(myChart);
    myChartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
    setContentPane(myChartPanel);
```