# Create Fatter Candlesticks in JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart, candlestick-chart

I'm developing an app that displays daily financial data, and have chosen to use JFreeChart. I was able to learn how to create a candlestick chart, but my problem lies in customization.

You see, what I'm aiming for is more along the lines of

[image: this]

While, so far all I've been able to manage is

[image: this].

No matter how far I zoom in, the candlesticks do not increase in width.

I'm fairly certain that somehow the thin candlesticks have something to do with being bound to a certain time range.. I've tried to remedy that but am not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

### SSCE

```
    public void showStockHistory(OHLCDataset dataset, String stockName) {
    JFreeChart candleChart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart("History of " + stockName, "Date", "Stock Points", dataset, true);

    XYPlot plot = candleChart.getXYPlot();
        plot.setDomainPannable(true);
        plot.setRangePannable(true);

    ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);

    NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setUpperMargin(0.0D);
        range.setLowerMargin(0.0D);
        range.setAutoRange(true);
        range.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(candleChart);
        chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true);

    getViewport().add(chartPanel);
    }
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18419795/230513) related to using a `SegmentedTimeline`.

Comment: @trashgod I'm not quite sure if it is related to that. In my case, the chart only displays thin candles regardless of dragging movement or zoom depth. Not sure what to do here.. so maybe I'll try playing around with Timelines to see if any changes occur..

Comment: Dragging just makes it easier to see, as the width waxes and wanes. You might also experiment with `setAutoWidthMethod()`.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks. Although its not exactly what I would call perfect, setting `setAutoWidthMethod()` to `CandlestickRenderer.WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST` more or less does fine considering the size of the data set I'm using.

Comment: Sounds like it's not a duplicate; I would encourage you to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although my given example seems to have to no differing method calls from the [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18413534/230513) in the first picture's code above, it nevertheless only shows thin candlesticks. I assume this to be some kind of bug.

However, I was able to rectify the issue as follows:

1. getting the renderer for the chart,
2. casting it to a type of `CandlestickRenderer`, and
3. setting its `setAutoWidthMethod()` method to `CandlestickRenderer.WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST`.

This is how you do it:

```
JFreeChart candleChart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(
    "History of " + stockName, "Date", "Stock Points", dataset, true);
XYPlot plot = candleChart.getXYPlot();
CandlestickRenderer renderer = (CandlestickRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setAutoWidthMethod(CandlestickRenderer.WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST);
```