# How to create a line chart using JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to create a line chart in my app for the first time which is going to show the trend of stock prices in my portfolio during the last five years. So I have time(year) in the horizontal line and the price in the vertical line. 
I am looking for a brief example similar to my case to go through it and implement mine. Does anybody know a similar example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18413534/230513).